# What are the ways to replace a fixed string (not regex) as a whole word in command line on Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, perl

What are the ways to replace a fixed string (not regex) as a whole word in command line on Linux?

For example I would like to replace literal "b.*c" as a whole word, with literal "\t", without escaping any characters, in file.txt:

```
1. abcd
2. a b c d
3. ab.*cd
4. ab.*c d
5. a b.*c d
```

Expected result:

```
1. abcd
2. a b c d
3. ab.*cd
4. ab.*c d
5. a \t d
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Replace instances of a word such as `red` with a word such as `blue`?

Comment: Do you just want to remove it or replace it with something? Add the expected output to your question.

Comment: How about `sed 's/b\.\*c/[something]/g' input.txt > output.txt`

Comment: What are the rules for replacing? A specific pattern or only the fifth line? What to do if line 4 is `a b.*c d` and line 5 `a b c d`?

Comment: @Toto Just find and replace a fixed string with a fixed string globally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command is:

`perl -p0e 's/\b\Qb.*c\E\b/\\t/g' file.txt`

```
$ cat file.txt
1. abcd
2. a b c d
3. ab.*cd
4. ab.*c d
5. a b.*c d

$ perl -p0e 's/\b\Qb.*c\E\b/\\t/g' file.txt
1. abcd
2. a b c d
3. ab.*cd
4. ab.*c d
5. a \t d
```

Thanks [Toto](https://superuser.com/a/1472522/687646), [glenn jackman](https://superuser.com/questions/1472464#comment2220157_1472522), and [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Quoting-metacharacters), [quotemeta](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) documentation

Answer (score 2):

A perl way wihout explicitly escaping special characters but using [`\Q`](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.30.0/functions/quotemeta.html):

```
perl -ane 's/\Q b.*c /\t/;print' file.txt
1. abcd
2. ab.*cd
3. ab.*c d
4. a b c d
5. a    d
```

Comment: In case `b.*c` occurs at the start or the end of the line, you could use `/\b\Qb.*c\E\b/` that puts the word boundaries *outside* the literal section.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with bash (version 4+) but it's gnarly

```sh
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ (^|.*[^[:alnum:]])"b.*c"([^[:alnum:]].*|$) ]]; then
        echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}\\t${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    else
        echo "$line"
    fi
done < file.txt
```

In a bash regex, quoted parts are literal.

If your're holding the pattern in a variable, you can't just put the variable in quotes -- then the regex metachars retain their special meaning. You can force escape each character though.

```sh
pattern="b.*c
for ((i=0; i<${#pattern}; i++)); do escaped+="\\${pattern:i:1}"; done
```

Then use

```sh
if [[ $line =~ (^|.*[^[:alnum:]])$escaped([^[:alnum:]].*|$) ]]; then
# ...............................^^^^^^^^.. unquoted
```

As I said, gnarly.

Comment: It's the only way that I googled up and that works on a bare-bones bash. It needs more upvotes!

Answer (score 0):

You can use "sed" to search for regular expression replacements.

```bsh
sed -r 's/(\s)b\.\*c(\s)/\1\\t\2/g'
```

In some versions of sed, the expression must be preceded option `-e`. E. In this case the `-re`.

#### Examples using:

```bsh
# source strings
sourceStrings="abcd\nab.*cd\nab.*c d\na b c d\na b.*c d"
pattern='s/(\s)b\.\*c(\s)/\1\\t\2/g'

# with `echo -e` for sh/bash, or `printf` for others shells
echo -e "$sourceStrings"| sed -r "$pattern"

# save string to file
printf "$sourceStrings" > file.txt

# replacing in content from file.txt with saving to another outputFile.txt
sed -r "$pattern" file.txt > outputFile.txt

# replacing in file
sed -ri "$pattern" file.txt
```

Comment: The answer has been improved: "__ReplacementWholeWord__" → "\t".

Comment: The question specifically asked NOT to search for a regex.